# Generate concentric circles in a meshgrid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate concentric circles in a meshgrid but the code I used only plots the borders of the circles.

```
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:1:4, theta);
a = 0;
b = 0;
plot(a+cos(Y).*X, b+sin(Y).*X);
axis equal
```

What I intend to do is to generate concentric circles that are filled and that the points inside the circles are valued as either 1 (white) or 0 (black). Below is a picture  for visualization. How do you code this using MATLAB?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use meshgrid a bit differently:

```
N=200;  % some size of grid
if mod(N,2) % odd vs even matrix sizes
        [x,y] = meshgrid(-(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2);
else
        [x,y] = meshgrid(-N/2+1:N/2);
end

x0=0; y0=0; % assuming the circle are always in the center, but we can modify this if needed 

% say we want a ring between `r1` and `r2`
f = @(r1,r2) (x-x0).^2+(y-y0).^2<=r2^2 & ...
             (x-x0).^2+(y-y0).^2>=r1^2;
```

now try:

```
imagesc(f(30,40)+f(50,60))
```

[image]

`f` is a logical matrix that has value 1 for the conditions given by an area between two circles of radius `r1` and `r2` .... you only care about the radius because the `theta` coordinate is always satisfied (or between 0 and 2pi) so it's not relevant...